# BeforeSendRequest breakpoint not hit

Tags: c#, wcf

i'm developing an small app, using a wcf service to provide data.
I want to add some headers to every message request, so i create an attribute inherit from IContractBehavior, then apply it to my service contract interface:

//SecuredServiceAttribute.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface, Inherited = true)]
public class SecuredServiceAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new ClientMessageInspector());
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new ServerMessageInspector());
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }
}
```

My ClientMessageInspector class as following:

// ClientMessageInspector.cs

```
public class ClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        MessageHeader header = MessageHeader.CreateHeader("smheader", "ns", "smvalue");
        request.Headers.Add(header);
        return null;
    }
}
```

and my ServerMessageInspector:

// ServerMessageInspector.cs

```
public class ServerMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        int found = request.Headers.FindHeader("smheader", "ns");
        if (found != -1)
        {
            string header = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>("smheader", "ns");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }
}
```

Now i apply SecuredServiceAttribute to the contract

// IService1.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
[SecuredService]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData();
}
```

The problem is: i put some breakpoint at BeforeSendRequest and AfterReceiveRequest but just AfterReceiveRequest  is hit up, so that request.Headers.FindHeader("smheader", "ns") always return -1 because the BeforeSendRequest is not run.

Here is my service model section at server side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

and client side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:59814/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="Service.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

Could you help me find what's wrong in my code?

Sorry i'm not good at English.